# In LSTM, in what scenario should one memory block have multiple memory cells?

Tags: machine-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I understand LSTM overall. But I would like to know why is it necessary for one memory block to have more than one memory cell. In most research papers it is mentioned that an RNN based on LSTM has the following structure: 1 input layer, 1 or more hidden layers, 1 output layer. Each hidden layer consists of memory blocks, where each memory block consists of one or more LSTM cell (the one that has one input, one output and one forget gate). The need for blocks and then cells is not clear.